# Powerline Glyphs Overlapping

Tags: oh-my-zsh, powerline

Shown in the image below, the git prompt has overlapping glyphs.

[image: Screenshot of powerline git extension]

I installed this theme by following the instructions listed [Here](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Install-Instructions#step-1-install-powerlevel9k). What doesn't make sense is that all prompts other than the git prompt look completely fine. So I guess the question is why would the git extension only be affected by this glyph misalignment?

I've been trying to do my best to research into any similar issues but could not find any thing outside of questions such as [this](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/Hack/issues/33).

The environment that I am using consists of the following

- Kubuntu 15.04
- Konsole
- Tmux
- zsh
- xterm-256color
- oh-my-zsh
- [powerline status bar](https://github.com/powerline/powerline)
- [powerlevel9k theme](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k)
- Font : ubuntu mono derivative powerline

My .zshrc contains these two lines to engage the powerlevel9k theme

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE="awesome-fontconfig"
```

Any insights on tweaking these glyphs will be incredibly helpful. So thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

powerlevel9k uses in "awesome-*" mode the [awesome-terminal-fonts](https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts/). Some of the glyphs in there are double-width, which is why we added some extra whitespace to these icons (see [here](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/blob/6d3899b6e39a4699bfe35038544ca366bcfdcade/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme#L110-L122)). Most of us use the "awesome-patched" mode, which requires pre-patched fonts, but is easier to install.

A quick shot would be to add some more whitespace. Could you try that, and if that works add a pull request? That would be nice.

Another guess in the wild is: what locale do you use? We had some strange issues with `LANG=C`. If that is the case on your machine, try setting it to a proper UTF8 one.